# No audio on 2010 MacBook Air

Tags: audio, headphones, speakers

I have my MacBook Air (late 2010) and it has been working fine for a good while. All of a sudden, for no reason,  (Okay, I may of dropped it but the drop was less than 1 foot and the Mac showed no damage after) the speakers don’t work and when I plug my 'kotion each' (headphones) into the port the audio symbol is grey and no audio ANYWHERE.

I have tried to wiggle the headphones and have looked many other places with no luck...

Answer (score 2):

A drop is a drop - 1 foot or 10 feet - you dropped it.

More than likely, you broke something on the I/O Board

[image: I/O board for 2010 MacBook Air]

[This goes for around $70 on Amazon](http://radnex.us/mba-dc-in-magsafe).  I just purchased one to fix a friends 2012 MBA and it was super easy to fix.  You just have to remove the back cover and one screw holds this board in place.  It removes pretty easily.

[image: I/O board location]

[iFixit has an excellent step-by-step guide](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Late+2010+I-O+Board+Replacement/4513) on how to replace it.

Answer (score -1):

Reboot your mac. thats all... really...